# CSS 3 PIE :hover not working

Tags: css, css3pie

IE is not displaying rounded corners. It works if I take out `:hover`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tooltip {
                position:absolute;
                text-decoration: none;
                display:inline-block;
            }
            .tooltip span {
                margin-left:-999em;             
            }
            .tooltip:hover span {
                background-color: black;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                color: #fff;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                left: 30px;
                padding: 10px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:1;
                behavior:url(PIE.htc);
                margin-left:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>This is a label
            <a href="#" class="tooltip">
                <img src="img/help.jpg" style="border:1px solid black;width:15px;height:15px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:5px;"/>
                <span>This is a test</span>
            </a>
        </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to set the span to watch for the behavior changes of the hovered element (in your case, the 'tooltip' element). Set the span to watch the 'tooltip' behavior changes by adding:

```
.tooltip span {
    -pie-watch-ancestors: 1;
}
```

'1' represents the level of the ancestor related to your rounded-bordered element.

More info here:
http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-watch-ancestors

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the behavior to the element without the :hover pseudo class:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tooltip {
                position:absolute;
                text-decoration: none;
                display:inline-block;
            }
            .tooltip span {
                margin-left:-999em;
                behavior:url(PIE.htc);          
            }
            .tooltip:hover span {
                background-color: black;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                color: #fff;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                left: 30px;
                padding: 10px;
                top:0px;
                z-index:1;
                margin-left:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>This is a label
            <a href="#" class="tooltip">
                <img src="img/help.jpg" style="border:1px solid black;width:15px;height:15px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:5px;"/>
                <span>This is a test</span>
            </a>
        </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

And you shouldn'd be hiding elements with negative margins:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tooltip {
                position:absolute;
                text-decoration: none;
                display:inline-block;
            }
            .tooltip span {
                left: 30px;
                top:0px;
                background-color: black;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px;
                display: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                behavior:url(PIE.htc);     
                z-index:1;
                position: relative;
            }
            .tooltip:hover span {
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>This is a label
            <a href="#" class="tooltip">
                <img src="img/help.jpg" style="border:1px solid black;width:15px;height:15px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:5px;"/>
                <span>This is a test</span>
            </a>
        </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Yes you can do this, but you must put the behavior declaration in a style rule that does not include a :hover selector. You can keep the rest of the styles in the :hover block.*
 follow this [IE at hover problem](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=329)

Try put your *behavior:url(PIE.htc);* in .tooltip{}. It's working for me.